# Mongoose Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Document'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, typescript

The ts compiler says that none of the properties exist on type 'Document'.

It seems that because of this none of the properties on the model can be set.
If I print a user object to the console all I get is 
{"_id":"long hex id number"}

My model is configured as follows:

users.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    firstMidname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword = setPassword;


userSchema.methods.validPassword = validPassword;

userSchema.methods.generateJwt = generateJwt;

export = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Api connection point
api.ts

```
import * as express from    'express';
import * as mongoose from   'mongoose';
import * as passport from   'passport';

var User = mongoose.model('User');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', createUser);

function createUser(req, res){
var user = new User();
    console.log(user);
    user.firstMidName = req.body.firstName;
    user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
    user.setPassword(req.body.password);

    user.save((err) => {
        console.log("saving user");
        var token;
        token = user.generateJwt();
        res.status(200);
        res.json({
            'token': token
        });
    });
}

export = router;
```

How can I fix or troubleshoot this issue? Nothing in the `user.save` block executes.

**EDIT:** The two things seem to be unrelated. I can now save to the database however the typescript error persists. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Isn't `user.generateJwt();` function asynchronous?

Comment: It isn't. I just truncated it from brevity. Also, the line saving user never logs which leads me to think that is isn't getting far enough for generateJwt to be the problem

Comment: @xerotolerant How did you solve this?

Comment: I’m not sure. I’ve been using typescript and mongoose a bit since then but I used typegoose in my most recent projects

Comment: I have same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934042/property-does-not-exist-on-type-modeldocumentany-any-any-t

Answer (score 24):

The `mongoose.model` method accepts a type that defaults to `mongoose.Document`, which won't have properties you want on your `User` document.

To fix this, create an interface that describes your schema and extends `mongoose.Document`:

```
export interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  email: {
    type: string;
    unique: boolean;
    required: boolean;
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, pass that through as the type for your model:

`export = mongoose.model<UserDoc>('User', userSchema);`

Comment: it shall be as simple as `export interface UserDocument extends Document {
  email: string
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934042/property-does-not-exist-on-type-modeldocumentany-any-any-t

Answer (score 2):

When I defined my entity interface I had it extending "Document" but had not imported anything.

When I crtl+click on it though I can see that it incorrectly thinks I was referring to the built-in node object "Document":

```
/** Any web page loaded in the browser and serves as an entry point into the web page's content, which is the DOM tree. */
interface Document extends Node, DocumentAndElementEventHandlers, DocumentOrShadowRoot, GlobalEventHandlers, NonElementParentNode, ParentNode, XPathEvaluatorBase {
```

After I explicitly told it to use Document from the mongoose library things worked.

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934042/property-does-not-exist-on-type-modeldocumentany-any-any-t

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by adding interface upon declaration of schema

```
interface UserInterface extends Document {
  email: string;
}

const User = new Schema<UserInterface>({
  email: String;
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934042/property-does-not-exist-on-type-modeldocumentany-any-any-t

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

I had the `Post` model defined as follows:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export interface iPost {
  title: string;
}

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema<iPost>({
  title: {
    type: String,
  }
});

export default mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

I tried using `Post.findByIdAndRemove(...);` but got the following error:

```
Property 'findByIdAndRemove' does not exist on type 'Model<iPost, {}, {}, {}, Document<unknown, {}, iPost> & iPost & { _id: ObjectId; }, Schema<iPost, Model<iPost, any, any, any, Document<unknown, any, iPost> & iPost & { ...; }, any>, ... 6 more ..., Document<...> & ... 1 more ... & { ...; }>>'.
```

I tried making my `iPost` interface extend `mongoose.Document` as suggested by the other answers **but it did not work.**

### Solution

The `findByIdAndRemove()` method is only available in mongoose v7 while I was using mongoose v8. The equivalent method for mongoose v8 is `findByIdAndDelete()`.

In Mongoose v8, there is also **no need** to make your interface extend `mongoose.Document`.

### Conclusion

Use the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html) for your mongoose version to **verify that the mongoose property that you are trying to use actually exists**.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly stated by @creme332, the `findByIdAndRemove()` method is only available in mongoose v7, and entirely removed in mongoose v8.

use `findByIdAndDelete()` instead. it work just find without extending any class.