# ERROR : TS2339: Property 'group' does not exist on type '{ rootCause: string; countermeasure?: any; signalName: any; importance: any; }[]'

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, javascript-objects

**Code:**

```
var dataArray: { rootCause: string, countermeasure?: any, signalName: any, importance: any }[] = []
dataArray.push({
            rootCause: x.description,
            countermeasure: response.countermeasures[ii],
            signalName: x.signalName,
            importance: x.importance
          })
const result = dataArray.group((data: any) => data.rootCause);
```

I`m just having an array of objects, and group method is for array itself.

**Error:**

```
TS2339: Property 'group' does not exist on type '{ rootCause: string; countermeasure?: any; signalName: any; importance: any; }[]'.
```

In the above code, group method is underlined with the red color.

Official docs to check its working [click me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group)

In there, its mentioned that its an experimental one, not sure if we could use it or not.
[image]


Similar question [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539216/error-ts2339-property-email-does-not-exist-on-type-object) to what I asked, but mine is not solved.


I made an example code to try out group() on https://onecompiler.com/javascript/, though in the compiler it says "group is not function" :
[image]
By this should I conclude that we cant use group method for array?

Comment: You are right. It's an experimental one. If we could see its [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group#browser_compatibility), it supports only on Safari. 
If you are developing in NodeJS, then we cannot use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, So official group() method is not working as intended bcz of the support issues. 
 To know more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group)

### But we could have our own walkaround for it as follows :

Let say the **data** that we have is as follows:

```
const products = [
  { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
];
```

**Required output:**

```
const groupByCategory = {
  'fruits': [
    { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' }, 
    { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
  ],
  'vegetables': [
    { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
  ]
};
```

**Code:**

```
const groupByCategory = products.reduce((group, product) => {
  const { category } = product;
  group[category] = group[category] ?? [];
  group[category].push(product);
  return group;
}, {});

console.log(groupByCategory);
```

**ScreenShot of the output :**
[image]
For more detailed information check [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-array-group/) .

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is only available for safari and safari on IOS.